# Combining Model Instances in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have to figures, a cone and a Box in libgdx:

```
   ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
      Model cone= modelBuilder.createCone(40f,250f,40f,8,cMaterial, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position|VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal|VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);
    Material tMaterial = new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.GRAY));
    Texture troncoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("t.jpg"));
    TextureAttribute taTronco = new TextureAttribute(TextureAttribute.Diffuse,troncoTexture);
    tMaterial.set(taTronco);
    Model cylinder= modelBuilder.createCylinder(20, 320, 20, 12, boxMaterial, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);
```

Is there any way I can combine both models into a new model or modelInstance so when I apply a transformation both models move at the same time?

Example:

```
Model myCominedModel = new Model(cone,cylinder) //Something like this is possible?
myCombinedModel.rotate(1,1,1,60) // Rotate both models
```

Comment: Why are you building two models, if you only want one? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder%2C-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder. Btw, don't use the `createXXX` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Why is not good to use the createXXX methods? I want to create a cone an a cylinder to make a sword. I also wanted to learn how to do it in code just for learning purposes.

Comment: Because they create a model containing only that shape. Which is okay for testing/debugging, but in any other case you probably want to show more than just than that single shape.

Comment: Thank you very much. The link you gave me has the info I need. I can mark your answer as correct if you post it with a brief explanation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ModelCache`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelCache) to merge one or more [`Models`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Models). That will merge them into the same Mesh and [render call](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch) where possible, which causes their individual transformation to be applied directly.

If you just want to add the Nodes of one model to the other then you could do that using `model1.nodes.add(model2.nodes);`. Note however that this does not make `model1` responsible for managing the resources of `model2`, you still need to dispose both models when you don't need `model1` anymore (but not before that). To fix that (and the references to the materials and such) you could use the static `ModelBuilder.rebuildReferences(model1)` method, after which you should discard `model2`, but *not* dispose it.

There are a few other options. E.g. to prevent having to deal with ownership of disposables you could combine the `ModelInstance` instead of the `Model`. You could also use `ModelBuilder` to create a new model and add the nodes of both models to it.

That said; in your example code you are first creating two separate models using `ModelBuilder` and then ask how you can combine them. You might as well build one model in the first place. Which would look something like (untested code):

```
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.begin();
modelBuilder.part("cone", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, cMaterial)
.cone(40f,250f,40f,8);
modelBuilder.part("cylinder", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, boxMaterial)
.cylinder(20, 320, 20, 12);
Model model = modelBuilder.end();
```

See [this link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder%2C-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder) for more information. Note that in your snippet you are creating a material without actually using it. You are also creating a Texture in there. Keep in mind that textures need to be disposed. If you want to make the model responsible for disposing it for you then you can call `modelBuilder.manage(troncoTexture)`.

Also note that if you don't need a separate material for both the cone and the cylinder that you don't need to create a separate `part()` for it. On the other hand, if you want to able to move them independently from each other within the model then you can call the `node()` method before each part.